# Wrapping side-effects in pure programming languages

Tags: monads, ml, uniqueness-typing

I'm researching possible ways to have computational effects in a pure programming language.

Monads are commonly presented as a way to wrap side effects in pure languages. I don't see how they help though. The problem I see is that monads can be copied or discarded.

In a pure language result of an operation should depend only on its arguments. But in a hypothetical language with

```
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

the code

```
let a = putStrLn "1"
let b = putStrLn "2"
in ()
```

will get type `Unit` and fail to capture presence of side effects.

I can later also

```
let a1 = do
  _ <- a
  _ <- putStrLn "2.1"
let a2 = do
  _ <- a
  _ <- putStrLn "2.2"
in ()
```

Presumably diverging (not latest) state `a` into two paths `a1` and `a2`. Or are all effects delayed until one selected `IO ()` term is returned from the main function? I'm wondering then how purposely copyable monads holding mutable state are compiled (when a monad indeed diverged, at which point and how was the state copied?)

In contrast unique type seems to be able to naturally capture presence of the only one context

```
putStrLn :: 1 IO () -> String -> 1 IO ()

main :: 1 IO () -> 1 IO ()
main io = 
  let a = putStrLn io "1"
  let b = putStrLn a "2"

  // compile error, a has type 0 IO ()
  // let a1 = putStrLn a "2.1"
  in b
```

Which seems to capture that the state is irreversibly modified and cannot be accessed again. Thus all results of function calls indeed depend only on their arguments.

Comment: Monads don't hold mutable state. They hold *operations* on mutable state. These operations come into play when a suitable interpreter runs them.

Comment: is the code a Haskell-like pseudocode? is it assumed to be lazy, or strict? in lazy Haskell, `let a = putStrLn "1" in
let b = putStrLn "2"
in ()` is just `()`.  In lazy Haskell, `let a = putStrLn "1" in let a1 = do {
  _ <- a ;
  _ <- putStrLn "2.1" ; return () } in 
let a2 = do {
  _ <- a ;
  _ <- putStrLn "2.2" ; return () }
in (a,a1,a2)`, all three values in the tuple are just pure values, no I/O is yet performed. if you have `main = do {a ; a1 ; a2}`, then when the executable runs, I/O actions described by `main` are performed (`a` will be done 3 times.)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: I didn't post this as an answer because I didn't know what you meant there, hence the questions in my comment. So I guess you did mean it as in (lazy) Haskell...

Comment: Hypothetical pure language based on ML. I used Haskell-alike syntax because that language seems to be mainstream now.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666618/possible-means-of-side-effectst-in-purely-functional-languages .